# How to compare current time with next day time in Android?

Tags: android

I'm creating a prayer app. In my app, I calculate upcoming prayer remaining time(by comparing current time) and my countdown timer starts. But, when last prayer(Isha) countdown timer ends then, I've to calculate countdown timer for tomorrow first(Fajr) prayer with current time.

I don't know how to calculate remaining time for tomorrow first prayer?

I've tomorrow first prayer(fajr) time. Please help.

Comment: Why are you using timer? You can use alarm manager to trigger on specific time like on prayer time.

Comment: it's my requirements to show countdown timer

Comment: i just want to calculate time difference between current time with tomorrow specific time.

Comment: convert your tomorrow time in milliseconds and you can get current time in milliseconds from System.currentTimeMillis().

Comment: @KarnShah can you tell me how i convert tomorrow time in milliseconds

Comment: in which format you are getting tomorrow time?

Comment: it's may be 12 or 24 hr format

Comment: say tomorrow fajr time is 4:00 am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use standard java classes then Calendar class is the best choice here. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

**Simple code**:

```
        Calendar nextDayCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextDayCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        nextDayCal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        nextDayCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        nextDayCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        nextDayCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);

        Calendar nowCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        int hourDif = nextDayCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - nowCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```